# the general solution to the system $x'=Ax+g(t)$ for the given matrix $A$ and vector $g(t)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the general solution to the system $x'=Ax+g(t)$ for the given matrix $A$ and vector $g(t)$ below.

$\mathbf{A} =
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -5 \\
1 & -2   
\end{array} \right)$
, $\mathbf{g(t)} =
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-\cos(t)  \\
\sin(t)    
\end{array} \right)$

Attempt: if  $\mathbf{x(t)} =
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_1(t)  \\
x_2(t)    
\end{array} \right)$
and
 $\mathbf{x'(t)} =
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_1'(t)  \\
x_2'(t)    
\end{array} \right)$ then we have

$x_1'(t)=2x_1(t)-5x_2(t)-\cos t$

$x_2'(t)=x_1(t)-2x_2(t)+\sin t$

How do we solve this system? Thanks!

Comment: do you know how to find two solutions of the homogeneous system $x' = Ax?$

Comment: I do not remember but I found how the method works from my book.

Comment: You can diagonalise and work in the complex domain to solve the problem. The matrix above has eigenvectors $(5  , 2\pm i)^T$. This lets you compute $e^{At}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you know how to solve the homogeneous system $$x_h' = Ax_h$$ as $$x_h=e^{At}$$

HINT: Use eigenvalues/eigenvectors. Once you have the answer to the homogeneous solution, you can compute the final solution by noting that $$x = x_h+x_p$$ where $x_p$ is a particular solution to this nonhomogeneous system. Guessing $$x_p = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} c_1\cos{t}+c_2\sin{t}\\c_3\cos{t}+c_4\sin{t}\end{array}\right)$$ and plugging into the original system $x_p'=Ax_p+g$ will allow us to solve for these coefficients and therefore the particular solution.

Comment: How do you guess the matrix $x_p$? Do you recommend some book about this?

Comment: You guess the particular solution vector (note: NOT a matrix) by looking at the forcing vector (or vector in your original system that is causing it to not be homogeneous). In this case, your $g(t)$ is a vector of cosines and sines, so you guess that your particular solution will be too. You probably already did this for single differential equations before learning about matrices.

Comment: @ErginSuer I often find that Paul's Online Notes are quite helpful whenever you're working on anything Calc I-III, Differential Equations, or Linear Algebra. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DE.aspx

Comment: I couldn't find the coefficients $c_1, c_2, c_3$ and $c_4$ by using the two equations.

Comment: You can split up those two equations by recognizing that the left and right hands of each equation have to be *identically* equal. Thus, the coefficients of the sines must be equal and the coefficients of the cosines must be equal. Now you have 4 equations and 4 unknowns.

Comment: Shouldn't be that some coefficients depend on $t$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24633/discussion-between-ergin-suer-and-noseknowsall).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Multiplying by $e^{-At}$, the equation becomes

$$(x'-Ax)e^{-At}=(xe^{-At})'=g(t)e^{-At}$$

and

$$x=e^{At}\int g(t)e^{-At}\,dt.$$